# Adding a subview between some objects

Tags: objective-c, addsubview

I have a scrollview in my view controller.

I'm adding a subview

```
UIImageView *IMG1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
IMG1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:IMG1];
IMG1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 35, 35);
```

So the question is how to add it under my scroller (between scroller and my view)?

Comment: What you have tried so far? your question unclear at least for me.

Comment: @iAmbitious The image appears above all objects on my view and image is needed to be under all objects on my view. Sorry for my awful english but I can't explain my problem better.

Comment: Edit your question whatever you tried code so far.

Comment: @iAmbitious that's all code I have

Comment: Where is code of  scroller and my view?? You added it in your nib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this content to ViewDidLoad and add the scrollView after imageView

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad]

UIImageView *IMG1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
IMG1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:MySubImage];
IMG1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 35, 35);
  [self.view sendSubviewToBack:IMG1];
//// add your scrollView and subViews 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have a lot of objects made not programmatically